# How to calculate the frequency of min and max temperatures from netcdf files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, netcdf, temperature

I have many netCDF files from climate models with data for temperature maxima and minima for a specific area. The files are of the form `A(latitude, longitude, temperature_values)` with monthly values.

I am trying to compare the values of two temperature maximum (or minimum) files in a way that I can show not only which of the two reaches higher maximum temperatures overall but also how  the frequency of "extreme" temperatures is higher in one of the two and how much.

Could anyone suggest a way on how to approach this in `MatLab`?

Comment: Have you tried `min` and `max` functions? Please [edit] your question to include: (1) a sample example of what you have (2) Exact expected output for the sample example

Comment: hi there, you need to define this " how the frequency of "extreme" temperatures is higher in one of the two and how much" more precisely in order for us to be able to suggest an answer. What do you mean by extreme? it can't be the max values (you refer to max vals before) as these by definition occur only once. Please try to formulate the question in a precise way.

Comment: ps: also the statement "which of the two reaches higher maximum temperatures overall" is ambiguous, do you mean overall in terms of over all the region, or do you mean gridcell by gridcell (i.e. model/file 1 may be the hottest in cell 1, model2/file2 in cell 2 etc).

Comment: finally your question seems to indicate that you have a separate file for each month, is this the case? so you want to know which model is highest for each particular month, presumably averaged all space?